# NSComparisonPredicate for empty to-many relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have a many-to-many relationship between two entities (EntityA and EntityB) in Core Data, and I'm trying to clean up the database periodically by removing instances of EntityB that no longer have any relationships to any instances of EntityA. I'm using [Mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator%E2%80%8E) to create the .m and .h files, which allows me to reference attribute/relationship names the way I do.

```
NSPredicate *noRelationPredicate = [NSComparisonPredicate predicateWithLeftExpression:[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"%K", EntityBRelationships.relationshipNameForEntityA] rightExpression:[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"nil"] modifier:NSDirectPredicateModifier type:NSEqualToPredicateOperatorType options:0];
```

However, I'm encountering the following error when I perform the fetch: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'

I'd prefer creating the predicate using the class method [NSComparisonPredicate predicateWithLeftExpression:rightExpression:modifier:type:options:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSComparisonPredicate_Class/Reference/NSComparisonPredicate.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSComparisonPredicate/predicateWithLeftExpression%3arightExpression%3amodifier%3atype%3aoptions%3a) as I try to avoid string literals in predicate creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a category to entity B that checks if it can be deleted.

```
-(void)willSave {
    if (!self.aRelations.count && !self.isDeleted) {
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:self];
    }
}
```

(By using a category in a separate file this code will not be overwritten if you want to re-generate your managed object subclasses.)

Comment: Seems like willSave is causing some sort of recursive behaviour to happen... I'm getting 'Failed to process pending changes before save.  The context is still dirty after 100 attempts.  Typically this recursive dirtying is caused by a bad validation method, -willSave, or notification handler.'

Comment: Actually I avoided this error by also checking if !self.deleted. Sometimes though, it seems like I'm deleting self too soon, as my incremental store later throws this error: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Comment: You could also try it with `-didSave`. Yes, I forgot to include the isDeleted check.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to specify what CoreData should do with "orphaned" instances when you define a relationship.  See "Relationship Delete Rules" here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW1

In particular, you may be able to use "Cascade" to handle the deletion for you.  From the documentation:

> Cascade
>
> Delete the objects at the destination of the relationship. For
>   example, if you delete a department, fire all the employees in that
>   department at the same time.

Comment: I tried using cascade before, but since it's a many-to-many relationship, it didn't seem to work as I expected. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding how it works, but I was unable to prevent deletion based on other factors... just ended up deleting the items that I didn't want to be deleted as well.